# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? DockerInDocker

Tags: docker, jenkins, cicd

I am getting the following error when running DockerInDocker!

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

The situation is :

I am having docker daemon running in my mac(intel) system. All the images and containers are maintained in host. Then i spawn a docker container (jenkins/jenkins). I want this container to connect to the dockerd of my host.

For this, i run the jenkins container using the following command

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /Users/nilotpalsarkar/.docker/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name jenkins -d jenkins-docker:1.0
```

In host mac, the docker.sock file is located in /Users/nilotpalsarkar/.docker/run
with permissions:

```
srwxr-xr-x  1 nilotpalsarkar  staff  0 Jun 21 17:53 docker.sock
```

The jenkins-docker image is built using the below docker file

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

# Install and downloads are done as root
USER root

# Required for maven plugin
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins maven-plugin:3.22
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins docker-build-publish:1.4.0

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/downloads
RUN mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home
RUN curl -L https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-17.03.0-ce.tgz |  tar xz -C /tmp/downloads
RUN curl -L https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk17/ri/openjdk-17+35_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz | tar xz -C /usr/local
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/local/jdk-17

ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# Docker daemon is removed, because thats not required in DinD. The docker image and container management would be performed
# by the host docker system.
RUN rm -rf /tmp/downloads/docker/dockerd

RUN mv /tmp/downloads/docker/docker* /usr/local/bin

# Remove the downloaded files - docker and jdk-17
RUN rm -rf /tmp/downloads
RUN groupadd -g 999 docker
RUN usermod -aG staff root
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/jenkins_home
```

I have added root user to staff group. The staff is a group in my host system and the docker.sock file has this group permission has i showed above.

Still when i fire docker --version in my jenkins container, i get the above error!

Any idea/help is appretiated!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some filesystem mapping issues using Docker Desktop.  Does `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` work better?  This would use the "host" path from inside the hidden Linux VM in Docker Desktop.  (Note, "Docker-in-Docker" usually refers to running a second Docker daemon in a container, rather than reusing the host's Docker socket.)